# Wrong static method resolution in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a struct with factory methods defined like this:

```
struct EvalValue
{
  enum ValueType { Float, Int, Null, NotNull } type; // NULL and NOT NULL are possible literals, so we need an enum for them.
  double number;

  EvalValue (ValueType aType, double aNumber) : type(aType), number(aNumber) {}
  static EvalValue fromBool(bool value) { return EvalValue(Int, value ? 1 : 0); };
  static EvalValue fromNumber(double number) { return EvalValue(Float, number); };
  static EvalValue fromInt(long long number) { return EvalValue(Int, (double)number); };
};
```

Using the following code in Visual Studio 2015:

```
EvalValue function test() {
  long long a = 0;
  return EvalValue::fromNumber(a);
}
```

leads to the warning:

> warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from '__int64' to 'double', possible loss of data

The compiler is clearly taking the wrong method as I have a dedicated variant for `long long`. What is the reason for that behavior? Needless to say that this works fine in clang and gcc without warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No compiler is right. You should be calling `fromInt` because that has a data type which matches with long long. gcc would also give a warning if you hit -Wall in your command.

Comment: No problem. I make worse mistakes. It is just a lack of attention for few seconds and things go wrong.

Comment: Upvote? Accept answer? I intend to beat Jon Skeet. :D

Comment: I can't yet. SO wants me to wait :-)

Comment: Curse SO. :P Bad for me.